# Define the link and controller of an Angular directive in separate files

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to split my directive in multiple files:

- coolParagraph.dir.js - directive
- coolParagraph.lnk.js - link function
- coolParagraph.ctl.js - controller

In this structure the controller is already in a separate file:

```
// paragraph.dir.js
angular.module('myModule')

.directive('coolParagraph', ['$interval', 'directiveTemplatePaths', function($interval, directiveTemplatePaths) {

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: link,
    controller: 'coolParagraph.controller',
    templateUrl: 'views/paragraph.tpl.html',
    scope: {}
  };

  function link(scope, element, attrs) {

  }

}]);


// paragraph.ctl.js
angular.module('myModule')

.controller('coolParagraph.controller', ['$scope', '$log', function($scope, $log) {

  $log.info("controller");

}]);
```

However since there is not an option like `angular.module('myModule').function` I was wondering how I could store the link function in a separate file as well.

Comment: I don't think that link function will need registration. You can first include the file having link function and then define the directive with the name of link function passed in.

Comment: If I do this link function would be global right? Which is something I like to avoid.

Comment: yeah thats the problem I don't have answer to :P :)

Comment: I wish I could do that too.. I'm aiming at separate files always - modules, controllers, components (without controller), directives, etc

Comment: But you gave a good idea! To register the function somewhere, being accessable through the closure and not polluting global scope. Like $templateCache, but for js!

Comment: Now, in theory, it _could_ be a [provider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#provider), which is the basic piece that creates all other providers (service, factory, etc). I'll try something and post as an answer if I succeed.. (sorry for the many comments)